# How to update indices rows automatically when couchdb is updated using elasticsearch in nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, couchdb

I am using elastic search and am new to this technology.I want to know **"how to update automatically elasticsearch indices rows when couchdb related document updated"?** 
For example 
I have couchdb data like below
purchage db rows

```
rows:[{
           "_id": "8ea64a80b67aff0ee12393b9",
           "_rev": "3-3d76a4f82bc4d3f8f7",
           "polines": [
               {
                   "stock_enabled_flag": "Y",
                   "charge_account_id": 23397,
                   "line_type": "Material",
                   "make1": "make1",
                   "need_by_date": "2012/11/23",
                   "promised_date": "2012/11/23",
                   "quantity": 80,
                   "unit_of_measure": "BAG",
                   "unit_price": 161.00021
               }
           ]
        },
{
           "_id": "8ea64a80b67aff0ee12393b99580",
           "_rev": "3-3d76a4f82bc4d3f8f7",
           "polines": [
               {
                   "stock_enabled_flag": "Y",
                   "charge_account_id": 23397,
                   "line_type": "Material",
                   "make1": "make1",
                   "need_by_date": "2012/11/21",
                   "promised_date": "2012/11/21",
                   "quantity": 80,
                   "unit_of_measure": "BAG",
                   "unit_price": 171.00021
               }
           ]
        }
,{
           "_id": "8ea64a80b67aff0ee12393b995",
           "_rev": "3-3d76a4f82bc4d3f8f7",
           "polines": [
               {
                   "stock_enabled_flag": "Y",
                   "charge_account_id": 23397,
                   "line_type": "Material",
                   "make1": "make1",
                   "need_by_date": "2012/11/22",
                   "promised_date": "2012/11/22",
                   "quantity": 80,
                   "unit_of_measure": "BAG",
                   "unit_price": 181.00021
               }
           ]

        }]
```

This my data.
I created indices for this db.
Then my requirement is when i add one row to couchdb then it will update in elasticsearch indices using nodejs.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

The node process can listen on [the changes feed of CouchDB](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html). Whenever it detects a change, let it update the elasticsearch indices.

There is also [CouchDB Lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene) which might be easier to use, but I am not sure if elasticsearch is a given requirement for your project and you can't easily change the technology stack.